# Need a solutions regarding session expire at any time in php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I use PHP  codeigniter. But there is one problem regarding session. Evenif i open single project in localhost, session expire at any time. It does not seem that it expire at fixed time. Sometimes session expire even within 5 min or sometimes it works for long times.

Can anybody suggest me what may be reason? and what is solutions. Sometimes when I do some change in code then session also expire.

Following configs are used in config.php file:

```
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;

$config['cookie_prefix']    = "";
$config['cookie_domain']    = "";
$config['cookie_path']      = "/";
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;

$config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;

$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'csrf_test_name';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrf_cookie_name';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;

$config['time_reference'] = 'local';
```

Comment: which version of Codeigniter you are using?

Comment: Currently I use 2.1.4

Answer (score 0):

For CodeIgniter 2 You have missed a configuration called `sess_expiration`.You may add it under `$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;`

```
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
```

It will keep session for 2 hours. But for this make sure `sess_expire_on_close` is set as `FALSE`

```
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
```

So final config is

```
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_expiration']     = 7200;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```